# URL Routing on shared server (GoDaddy)

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, shared-hosting

I am working on one web application in which user have to send his/her reference number to anyone to show their details.

Like :

http://www.Snapshotprofile.com?Profile=sunny16dhiman161507

But i want to use

http://www.Snapshotprofile.com/sunny16dhiman161507

How i can do this. I had searched a lot on web but didn't get any specific answer.
Please let me know if require more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on ASP.Net 4.0 then you can use its built in Routing feature. Or you need some third party element like [UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/). Also there is a very nice article on the same by Scott Gu, [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: @Sunny then you need to keep on search as these contains very basic funda of rewriting to start with